# Bulk Insert into view and find missing values

Tags: sql-server-2012, view, bulk-insert

I have 2 tables, Categories, and SubCategories:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbCategories]
(
  [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CategoryName] [varchar](250) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbSubCategories]
(
  [SubCategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
  [SubCategory] [varchar](250) NULL
)
```

I want to Import Sub-Categories with a csv file, which contains the CategoryName and the SubCategory.

Here's an example:

[image]

So I get the CategoryName and the Sub-Category Name.  But I need the CategoryID. The user won't know what that is, they will only know the Category Name. What would be this best way to do this?

I already have a bulk insert method (using c#) that works fine if I import a csv file with CategoryID and SubCategoryName.  I thought I can insert into a view to achieve this. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vSubCategories]
AS

SELECT c.CategoryName, s.SubCategory
FROM dbo.tbCategories c 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubCategories s 
ON c.CategoryID = s.CategoryID
```

Then I can use a trigger with 'INSTEAD OF INSERT'.  But how do I get SQL to automatically pick up the CategoryID which should be inserted into SubCategory table?

In short, I want to import the csv file above, and see something similar in the tbSubCategories table as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of this answer, I am assuming your INSERT statement looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.vSubCategories (CategoryName, SubCategory)
SELECT
  CategoryName,
  SubCategory
FROM
  ...  /* reading rows either from the CSV directly or
          from a staging table into which the CSV has been imported */
;
```

So, the first thing your trigger needs to do is to insert the (new) categories into *tbCategories*:

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.tbCategories (CategoryName)
SELECT
  CategoryName
FROM
  inserted
EXCEPT  -- do not insert already existing category names
SELECT
  CategoryName
FROM
  dbo.tbCategories
;
```

Now all the category names in the imported dataset can be mapped to their IDs using the *tbCategories* table. And that is what the trigger should do when inserting the subcategories:

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.tbSubCategories (CategoryID, SubCategory)
SELECT
  c.CategoryID,
  n.SubCategory
FROM
  inserted AS n
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbCategories AS c ON n.CategoryName = c.CategoryName
EXCEPT  -- exclude existing sub-categories, just in case
SELECT
  CategoryID,
  SubCategory
FROM
  dbo.tbSubCategories
;
```

For reference, here is a complete trigger script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.vSubCategories_InsteadOfInsert
ON dbo.vSubCategories
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  -- insert categories
  INSERT INTO
    dbo.tbCategories (CategoryName)
  SELECT
    CategoryName
  FROM
    inserted
  EXCEPT  -- do not insert already existing category names
  SELECT
    CategoryName
  FROM
    dbo.tbCategories
  ;
  -- insert sub-categories
  INSERT INTO
    dbo.tbSubCategories (CategoryID, SubCategory)
   SELECT
    c.CategoryID,
    n.SubCategory
  FROM
    inserted AS n
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbCategories AS c ON n.CategoryName = c.CategoryName
  EXCEPT  -- exclude existing sub-categories, just in case
  SELECT
    CategoryID,
    SubCategory
  FROM
    dbo.tbSubCategories
  ;
END;
```

Comment: This answer was perfect! Thanks so much for the answer and the explanation!